# How to rename file with first 32 characters of text file with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I would please like someone to help me with this code (shown below). All i want is the new file name needs to be the first 32 characters of the first line of the file?

```
cd c:\test2\test
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b *.txt') do (
set nname=
set fname=%%i
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%%i") do if not defined nname set "nname=%%f"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "nname=!nname:~0,40!"
rename "!fname!" "!nname!"
endlocal
)
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd /d c:\test2\test
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b *.txt') do (
set nname=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in ("%%i") do if not defined nname set "nname=%%f"
set "nname=!nname:~0,32!"
rename "%%i" "!nname!%%~xi"
)
```

Comment: Thanx allot!! Such a small fix... :)

Comment: Just one more question... how do I add the current date after the new file name? example: newfile 01012001.txt

Comment: Disregard previous question. Fixed by adding: for /f "tokens=1-5 delims=/ " %%m in ("%date%") do rename "*.*" "* %%m-%%n-%%o" to end of batch file.